# How to add one to many relationship based on custom property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have two entities:

```
public class Customer
{
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     public Guid CustomerKey { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public Guid CustomerKey { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

1 customer can have many products, but I want to bind them based on `CustomerKey` property. Here is sample of example data:

```
CustomerId | CustomerKey
    1      | {00000000-0000-0000-0000-111111111111}
    2      | {00000000-0000-0000-0000-222222222222}

ProductId  | Name     | CustomerKey
    1      | Product1 | {00000000-0000-0000-0000-111111111111}
    2      | Product2 | {00000000-0000-0000-0000-111111111111}
    3      | Product3 | {00000000-0000-0000-0000-222222222222}
```

So first customer has first two products and the second customer has the last product. I tried doing something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(m => m.Products);
}
```

But how do I specify that I want to bind them on `CustomerKey`?

Comment: Change CustomerId to a `Guid` and delete `CustomerKey`.  Primary/Foreign keys can be ints or Guids.

Comment: @Neil I cannot. I have to have `Id`, because `CustomerKey` is not unique and as you can see there may be many rows with the same key.

Comment: So you are saying that different customer id can have the same customer key????

Comment: @Neil Yes. This makes more sense when you think of multiple customers with the same key as different versions of the same customer.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but only if the `CustomerKey` property (column) of the `Customer` is unique. This is EF Core requirement (actually relational database FK requirement, but EF Core supports only relationships which can be represented as relational database FK constraints), so if it's not, then what you are asking is not possible.

The fluent API for that is [`HasPrincipalKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencecollectionbuilder-2.hasprincipalkey?view=efcore-2.1) method:

> Configures the unique property(s) that this relationship targets. Typically you would only call this method if you want to use a property(s) other than the primary key as the principal property(s). If the specified property(s) is not already a unique constraint (or the primary key) then a new unique constraint will be introduced.

And of course the FK is configured as usual with [`HasForeignKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencecollectionbuilder-2.hasforeignkey?view=efcore-2.1).

Applying it to your model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(customer => customer.Products)
    .WithOne() // no navigation property
    .HasForeignKey(product => product.CustomerKey)
    .HasPrincipalKey(customer => customer.CustomerKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare both classes with navigation properties to each other. Mark one of the tables (the dependent table) with the `ForeignKey` attribute on its Primary Key.

```
public class Customer
{
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     [Index("IX_Customer_Key", 1, IsUnique = true)]
     public Guid CustomerKey { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public Guid CustomerKey { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("CustomerKey")]
     public Customer Customer{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This still tries to map `Products` to `ProductId`